# Para que serve a meta tag com atributo itemprop="image"?

Tags: html, html-meta-tag

Por curiosidade, eu utilizei a opção do Google Chrome para poder visualizar o código-fonte do Google, e lá encontrei uma meta tag com um atributo `itemprop="image"`.

Assim:

```
<meta 
content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" 
itemprop="image" />
```

Alguém sabe para que serve isso? Nunca li nada a respeito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é referente ao site schema.org para tratar microdados, **Rich Snippets**.

> ### [ImageObject](http://schema.org/ImageObject)
>
> schema.org > Thing > CreativeWork > MediaObject > ImageObject
> An image file.
> Usage: Over 1,000,000 domains

Esse exemplo de `itemprop="image"` está nesse link acima.

É para o SEO do site. Melhora, e muito, se souber usar. Eu uso para produtos, serviços, redes sociais e imagens.

No site do Google Developers tem um teste que se faz para ver se o Google encontra os dados estruturados: [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).

Comment: Obrigado, cara. Tá me ajudando para caramba :)

Comment: @Diego Souza com isso ai então conseguimos definir tipo a imagem que vai representar o site nos motores de busca?