# É correto repetir o atributo itemprop?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Queria saber se repetir `itemprop` dessa forma está errado. Na verdade, eu quero mostrar 3 produtos e colocar os respectivos `itemprop` de cada situação:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="imagem_do_produto1.jpg" alt="produto1">
<h5 class="card-title" itemprop='makesOffer'>produto1</h5>

<img class="card-img-top" src="imagem_do_produto2.jpg" alt="produto2">
<h5 class="card-title" itemprop='makesOffer'>produto2</h5>

<img class="card-img-top" src="imagem_do_produto3.jpg" alt="produto3">
<h5 class="card-title" itemprop='makesOffer'>produto3</h5>
```

Está correto dessa forma?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91330/8063

Comment: Bom também: https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/

Comment: https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemprop

Answer (score 0):

Não é proibido, estar correto vai depender da finalidade a que quer chegar ao utilizar este atributo.

[Como dito](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop) :

> O atributo global  itemprop é usado para adicionar propriedades para um item. Todo elemento HTML pode ter um atributo itemprop  especificado, e um itemprop consiste em um par de nome e valor. Cada par de nome e valor é chamado de propriedade, e um grupo de uma ou mais propriedades forma um item.

Vai depender do [itemscope](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemscope)

Comment: o itemscope é organization...